# Prevent facetime from asking for password in Mavericks

Tags: macos, password, facetime

Some time ago I've updated to OSX Mavericks. Since then each time after the system starts I get a prompt to enter Facetime password. How to disable this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution:

- Open FaceTime,
- Open "FaceTime" menu,
- Choose "Turn FaceTime off" option.

Comment: glad to see you answered your question that was bit misleading. You wanted to disable facetime, not have it autocomplete the password entry.

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure what I want to do, I just wanted the dialog to disappear :-)

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX: I can do that in two days.

Comment: The option is greyed out.

Comment: @Stuntddude Once you log in (hopefully just this one last time), the option becomes available.